# Javascript JSON display hashtag symbol

Tags: javascript, json

I'm saving some data through the URL and one of these data elements is a text. I want to be able to save and store notes with hashtags on them. For example, I want to be able to save "I believe in #yolo", but when I save it (through php), and retrieve it again with javascript, I get "I believe in". Anyway, I can get that #yolo back? I tried using str_replace, but I may have gotten the regex wrong.

Thanks for all the help!

```
    function dropsuccess() {
        answerArray = [];
        answerArray.id = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
        answerArray.text = document.getElementById("boglory").value;
        $.getJSON("saveBlade.php?id="+answerArray.id+"&text="+answerArray.text,
        function(data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty("error")) {
                alert(data.error);
                } else {
                    $("#handle").animate({marginTop:"100%"},800, 
                    function() {
                        document.getElementById("handle").style.display = "none";document.getElementById("bladecontainer").style.display = "none";$('#qod').fadeIn('medium');
                    });     
            }
        });     
    }
```

answerArray.text includes the text that is being passed. Ex ("I believe in #yolo.") #yolo is a string, not a div-id tag.

Comment: How about some code? Do you mean that your url contains an #?

Comment: Yeah, it sends the message with the # in the URL. I'll edit the post with some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `#` is a reserved character in URLs to indicate a jump to an anchor.

You need to escape it. JQuery automaticly escape all characters that need to if you supply them as the data argument in the getJSON function:

```
$.getJSON("saveBlade.php",
  {
    id: answerArray.id,
    text: answerArray.text
  },
  function(data) {
```

Look [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) for details